# select all rows from table1, and rows from table2 that are not in table 1

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

I tried many solutions (joins, unions etc.) but so far i couldn't get the wanted result, now i'm just confused...
I have two tables:

table1

```
ID - Name

0 - John

1 - Jack

2 - Anna

3 - Liam

4 - Luke
```

table2

```
ID - FullName - City

0 - John Smith - New York

1 - Jack Smith - Houston

2 - Anna Smith - Houston

'' - Owen Smith - Chicago

'' - Rosa Smith - Chicago
```

Some rows may be in table 1 but not in table 2 and some are in table2 but not in table 1.
I need to select ALL the rows of table 1 and all the rows in table2 minus the ones that match ID in both table, and as results i need to have all the needed columns to know where the results come from.
 Something like:

results:

```
ID - Name - FullName - City

0 - John - John Smith - '' (name!='' so i know it's from table1)

1 - Jack - Jack Smith - '' (name!='' so i know it's from table1)

2 - Anna - Anna Smith - '' (name!='' so i know it's from table1)

3 - Liam - '' - '' (name!='' so i know it's from table1)

4 - Luke - '' - '' (name!='' so i know it's from table1)

'' - '' - Owen Smith - Dallas (name='', city!='' so i know it's from table2)

'' - '' - Rosa Smith - Las Vegas (name='', city!='' so i know it's from table2)
```

I hope the example i made is clear enough, thanks.

Comment: and what happens when whoy have also a Jack B Smith. What you need is a full OUTERm JOIN which mysql doesn't have.

Comment: Full join in MySQL is a faq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the two tables relate through their `id`, this should do what you want:

```
select id, name, t2.fullName, t2.city
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
union all
select t2.id, null, t2.fullName, t2.city
from table2 t2
where not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.id = t2.id)
```

Another option is aggregation:

```
select id, max(name) name, max(fullName) fullName, max(city) city
from (
    select id, name, null fullName, null city from table1 
    union all
    select id, null, fullName, city from table2
) t
group by id
```

Comment: Thank you! I achieved the desired result working a little with the aggregation option!